# How can I add reference lines in uplot?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts

Because of the high rendering performance I am using [uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot) to visualize historical sensor data.
Is there a way to add horizontal reference lines like recommended min/max values for a data series?
With other libraries that's often straight forward, like the [ReferenceLine tag in recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ReferenceLine), but I haven't found anything yet with uPlot. Any hints?

Example: The orange dotted lines are the lower and upper acceptable bounds at 7.0 and 7.4. This image is rendered with recharts, but I want to migrate to uplot.

[image]

(There's a layer in front of the chart with the actual, min and max value which is totally independent of the chart.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an acceptable aproach based on two examples in the uPlot repository:

https://leeoniya.github.io/uPlot/demos/trendlines.html
https://leeoniya.github.io/uPlot/demos/draw-hooks.html

The main idea is to handle one of the draw-hooks (draw, drawAxes, drawClear) and to directly drawing on the canvas.